# How to rewrite the url if it does not have a prefix with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The page should always have the prefix 'es', 'en', or 'fr' after the main domain, if someone type a url without the prefix then it should be set  'es' by default.
Example:

```
www.mypage.com/games/sports -> www.mypage.com/es/games/sports
```

if it has any of the prefixes then it does not change.

```
www.mypage.com/en/games/sports -> www.mypage.com/en/games/sports
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(es|en|fr)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```